# How can I make drop down menu to be working in mobile device?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

[You can see live site here](http://d3sine.com/demo/nana/). I want to make the drop down menu working on mobile device. In other words, when tapped the menu, sub menus will show and if user tapped any area except main menus that have sub menu inside, the sub menus will be invisible.

PS. JavaScript is already embedded in the header section. Feel free to look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind the "click" function to open/close the menu, in this case they will remain opened until the next click.

Or you can use jquery to do it, using the slideToggle function.

```
$('#jsddm > li').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(ddmenuitem).slideToggle();
})
```

Anyway, I suggest you to use a responsive template - probably one of the best could be Skeleton Grid (easy to find on Google, and easy to use), that will adapt your template to all the screen resolutions.
Have a look on it!
Cheers
Marco

Comment: Where should I put your code? I have tried to put inside and outside of document.ready and it doesn't work. After I tapped the menu, the submenu appears for a second and then gone forever until I refresh the browser.

Comment: Put it in the document.ready, and comment the previous script you did.I suggest to update your jquery version also!

Comment: Okay, but how can I keep the mouseover and mouseout binding?